# Solr Score undestanding

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a simple query: `myfield:abc OR myfield:def OR myfield:asd`

"`abc`","`def`" and "`asd`" are 3 types of overall 10 types ("`abc`", "`def`", "`asd`", "`gfd`", "`kuh`", "`rud`", "`sew`", "`saw`", "`xct`", "`mmu`").

My problem is, that i want to sort by score but the result will have a different score because of my query. If i set `*:*` as the query, every document has got the same score.
If i search with that above query every type has got a different score.

In example:
Every document of type "`abc`" got score 10. Every document of type "`def`" got score 6 and so on.

First i thought it is the order of the query, but if i change it to `myfield:asd OR myfield:def OR myfield:abc` nothing seems to change.

Can somebody tell me to avoid this? Or why this happend?

Thanks

---

This are some parts of my schema.xml

```
<field name="myfield" type="search" indexed="true" stored="true" omitTermFreqAndPositions="true" omitNorms="true"/>

<fieldType name="search" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mappings.txt"/>
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mappings.txt"/>
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

I added omitTermFreqAndPositions and omitNorms but the result is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

The order wont change the score of the query.

Add debugQuery=on as a parameter to HTTP-request and you can see how scores are calculated.